# MVC4 Create View From Enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view I want to create/save and instead of a model use an enum as follows.

```
public enum RulesEnum
{
    StopAtLight = 1,
    StopAtStreet,
    StopAtCrossWalk,
    WaitAtCrossWalk,
}
```

The Model

```
public class RulesModel
{
    public RulesEnum Rules { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; } 
    // some other props that you have
}
```

The View

```
    @model RulesModel
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        <input type="radio" name="Rules" value="0" id="Rules1_No" />
        <input type="radio" name="Rules" value="1" id="Rules1_Yes" />
        <label for="Rules1">Stop at Light</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Rules" value="0" id="Rules2_No" />
        <input type="radio" name="Rules" value="1" id="Rules2_Yes" />
        <label for="Rules2">Stop at Street</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Rules" value="0" id="Rules3_No" />
        <input type="radio" name="Rules" value="1" id="Rules3_Yes" />
        <label for="Rules3">Stop at CrossWalk</label>
        <input type="text" name="Rules" id="Rules4" />
        <label for="Rules4">Wait at CrossWalk</label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
```

The Controller Action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TheMethodThatAcceptsTheInput(RulesModel model)
{
    // do as you wish here, I assume you already know what to do here
    // at this point, if the user selects a radio button 
    // then the model.Rules will show it, as an enum value of course
    return View(model);
}
```

This previous snippet just demonstrates that each enum value would have a different control associated with it.  So essentially I'd like to define different controls for each enum value.

I will want to create a list of KeyValuePairs so I can send the value the user selected for each enum value back to the controller.  However, with my limited knowledge, I only know how to send a well defined model back to the controller.  How do I build up my list of KeyValuePairs and send them back to the controller when the user presses the submit button?

I've looked into various alternatives such as AutoMapper and ViewModels, but I don't think my specific problem is related to these solutions.  I am fairly new, can anyone lend some guidance on the best way to solve this problem?

Thanks!

UPDATE:
Looking at Von's example I've modified mine a little bit.  The only difference is that I don't want a list of the enums (meaning 4 enum values = 4 radio buttons) but I'd like each enum value to be a question, ex:

> Stop at light?  yes/no (2 radio buttons) 
>   Stop at street? yes/no (2 radio buttons) 
>   Stop at crosswalk? yes/no (2 radio buttons) 
>   Wait at crosswalk? 30 seconds (text box)

What I don't know how to do is to for example, the user clicks submit.  I need to somehow look at each question and build the list to send to the controller so it would look like the following:

```
[(StopAtLight, "false"),
 (StopAtStree, "true"),
 (StopAtCrossWalk, "false"),
 (WaitAtCrossWalk, "40")]
```

Not sure how I can build this list when the user presses submit since it's expecting a model similar to what Von posted.

Hopefully this further information helps to understand my situation.  Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Please rephrase your question, and/or provide your current (relevant) controller's action methods and view models or just models.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you wanted to do with the KeyValuePairs but based on the markup in your question you want to show the enum as options on your page and then have some textboxes for input and them submit them to your controller. If that's the case then you can do the following:

The Model

```
public class RulesModel
{
    public bool StopAtLight { get; set; }
    public bool StopAtStreet { get; set; }
    public bool StopAtCrossWalk { get; set; }
    public string WaitAtCrossWalk { get; set; }
    // some other props that you have
}
```

The View

```
@model RulesModel
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <h1>Stop at Light</h1>
    <input type="radio" name="StopAtLight" value="false" id="Rules1_No" />
    <label for="Rules1_No">No</label>
    <input type="radio" name="StopAtLight" value="true" id="Rules1_Yes" />
    <label for="Rules1_Yes">Yes</label>
    <h1>Stop at Street</h1>
    <input type="radio" name="StopAtStreet" value="false" id="Rules2_No" />
    <label for="Rules2_No">No</label>
    <input type="radio" name="StopAtStreet" value="true" id="Rules2_Yes" />
    <label for="Rules2_Yes">Yes</label>            
    <h1>Stop at CrossWalk</h1>
    <input type="radio" name="StopAtCrossWalk" value="false" id="Rules3_No" />
    <label for="Rules3_No">No</label>
    <input type="radio" name="StopAtCrossWalk" value="true" id="Rules3_Yes" />
    <label for="Rules3_Yes">Yes</label>            
    <h1>Wait at CrossWalk</h1>
    <input type="text" name="WaitAtCrossWalk" id="WaitAtCrossWalk" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

The Controller Action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TheMethodThatAcceptsTheInput(RulesModel model)
{
    // if model.StopAtLight == false then the user selected No otherwise it was Yes
    // same goes for the rest of the radio buttons
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Von!  You basically have the right idea of what I am trying to do, sorry but this one was hard for me to get out of my head and in the form of a question, so that one was my fault.  Please see my edited version, I've used your example as a starting point.

Comment: I've modified my answer based on your updated question. You really are using enums rather strangely.